# Wireless connection breaks down

Tags: wireless, networking

I'm having trouble staying connected to the internet at work.  It's strange because that hasn't happened with my home network, but there's something about the office's -probably more complicated- that randomly disconnects me all the time.

Details:

> - It doesn't happen to other computers.
> - Even the IT guys don't know what's going on.
> - Once it disconnects, it won't connect again until I restart the computer (pfff).    After that, it just won't find the connection.
> - It may happen within 5 minutes or a couple of hours.
> - It happens with both secure and guest connections.
> - The only remedy so far is to use Ethernet cable, which at the point is not very doable.
> - I have Ubuntu 14.04.
> - I don't know about networks, or commands for the terminal, so any of those are welcome too.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the driver packages:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install build-essential libssl-dev linux-headers-`uname -r` linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix it.  If you have any other suggestions I'll be grateful.